# Heroku Run Rails Console Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, terminal, console

```
$ heroku run rails c
-bash: heroku: command not found
```

I don't get it. Isn't that how you are suppose to startup the heroku console?

Comment: Don't add irrelevant links like that, it is spammy and bad behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) first, and then try again your `heroku run rails c` command.

To verify your toolbelt installation use:

```
$ heroku --version
```

See [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize when I upgraded my mac I had to reinstall it. Thanks again.